# In a For-Loop: How to compare a value with values in a groupby function

Tags: python, for-loop, conditional-statements, pandas-groupby, conditional-operator

How can i compare a row to a group of values? I am trying to iterate through individual IDs in grouped time windows and compare the unique ID to the values of other IDs in the time interval. The conditional statement wants to only consider the ones below or above the thresholds and if True, then attach the value 1 in a new column.

I have following code:

```
time = np.array([1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3])
ids = np.array([3271,3229,4228,2778,4228,3271,3229,3229,4228,2778,4228,3271,4228,3229,3271])
vec_len = np.array([,0.1,0.5,-0.0,0.0,0.1,-0.7,-0.3,-0.8,-0.6,0.2,0.1,-0.7,-0.3,-0.8])
quad = np.array([7,0,0,5,0,6,5,2,5,5,0,6,5,2,5])

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': time, 'id': ids, 'vec_len': vec_len, 'id': ids})
df['intera'] = np.array(0)

id_group=df.groupby(['time'])

interaction = []
for g_idx, group in id_group:
    for r_idx, row in group.iterrows():
        if (row['vec_len'] > group.groupby('id')['vec_len'].quantile(0.75) or row['vec_len'] < 
                       group.groupby('id')['vec_len'].quantile(0.25)):
            interaction.append('1')
```

Can anyone help?

```
time   id   vec_len  quadrant   interaction  

1    3271    0.9    7   0 
1    3229    0.1    0   0
1    4228    0.5    0   0
1    2778   -0.3    5   0
2    4228    0.2    0   0
2    3271    0.1    6   0
2    3229    -0.7   5   1    
2    3229    -0.3   2   0
2    4228    -0.8   5   1    
2    2778   -0.6    5   1    
3    4228    0.2    0   0
3    3271    0.1    6   0
3    4228    -0.7   5   1    
3    3229    -0.3   2   0
3    3271    -0.8   5   1
```

Comment: The first element of `vec_len` is missing and the values are not the same as in your example. `vec_len[3]` is `-0.0` in the code, yet it's `-0.3` in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you first calculate the quantiles and then apply your logic to get the interaction variable. There is rarely a need to iterate over a DataFrame's rows with a loop, usually there is a faster method available.

You could do something like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': time, 'id': ids, 'vec_len': vec_len, 'id': ids})
grp = df.groupby(['time', 'id'])
quantiles = grp.vec_len.quantile([.25, .75]).unstack(level=2).reset_index()
df = df.merge(quantiles, on=['time', 'id'])
df.loc[:, 'intera'] = df[['vec_len', 0.25, 0.75]].apply(
    lambda x: 1 if x[0] < x[1] or x[0] > x[2] else 0, axis=1
)
```

If you don't need the quantile variables, you can then just drop them.

Comment: Thank you so much, but why cant i merge the two series?

Comment: Do you mean merging the quantile series at the same time?

Comment: This code errors at quantiles = pd.merge(quant_25, quant_75, on=['time', 'id']) saying. "ValueError: Cannot merge a Series without a name".

Comment: Copy pasting the above works in python 3.7. In any case, try the updated answer.

Comment: this is super nice of you thank you very much, this was great help!! The next step is to pair the interaction IDs in a new column. In case you know an easy way?

Comment: You can ask a new question for that. Could you accept the answer if it solved your problem?